# Exception: il2cpp.exe did not run properly

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, exe, il2cpp

I can't build Android.

```
Exception: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/deploy/net471/il2cpp.exe did not run properly!
```

---

```
Exception: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/deploy/net471/il2cpp.exe did not run properly!

Failed running "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/deploy/net471/il2cpp.exe" --convert-to-cpp --emit-null-checks --enable-array-bounds-check --dotnetprofile="unityaot" --compile-cpp --libil2cpp-static --platform="Android" --architecture="ARM64" --configuration="Release" --outputpath="C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\Yazılım\Unity Engine\Oyun Projeleri\the game\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Native\arm64-v8a\libil2cpp.so" --cachedirectory="C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\Yazılım\Unity Engine\Oyun Projeleri\the game\Assets\..\Library\il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache" --additional-include-directories="C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools\bdwgc/include" --additional-include-directories="C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools\libil2cpp/include" --tool-chain-path="C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK" --profiler-report --map-file-parser="C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/Tools/MapFileParser/MapFileParser.exe" --directory="C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yazılım/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Temp/StagingArea/assets/bin/Data/Managed" --generatedcppdir="C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yazılım/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Temp/StagingArea/Il2Cpp/il2cppOutput"  

stdout:
Building libil2cpp.so with AndroidToolChain
    Output directory: C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\Yaz�l�m\Unity Engine\Oyun Projeleri\the game\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Native\arm64-v8a
    Cache directory: C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\Yaz�l�m\Unity Engine\Oyun Projeleri\the game\Library\il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a\il2cpp_cache
ObjectFiles: 150 of which compiled: 150
    Time Compile: 62646 milliseconds Lump_libil2cpp_vm.cpp
    Time Compile: 37545 milliseconds Lump_libil2cpp_icalls.cpp
    Time Compile: 27020 milliseconds Il2CppAttributes.cpp
    Time Compile: 26401 milliseconds Unity.TextMeshPro2.cpp
    Time Compile: 24314 milliseconds Unity.TextMeshPro3.cpp
    Time Compile: 23081 milliseconds Il2CppInvokerTable.cpp
    Time Compile: 19947 milliseconds Unity.TextMeshPro4.cpp
    Time Compile: 19739 milliseconds gc.c
    Time Compile: 18282 milliseconds mscorlib14.cpp
    Time Compile: 18125 milliseconds Generics8.cpp
Total compilation time: 341853 milliseconds.
il2cpp.exe didn't catch exception: Unity.IL2CPP.Building.BuilderFailedException: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++ @"C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpB14F.tmp" -o "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\Yaz�l�m\Unity Engine\Oyun Projeleri\the game\Library\il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a\il2cpp_cache\linkresult_4C3FB6CB254594B3D079323B5CB3389C\libil2cpp.so" -shared -Wl,-soname,libil2cpp.so -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--build-id -stdlib=libc++ -static-libstdc++ -target aarch64-linux-android21 -Wl,--wrap,sigaction -llog -rdynamic -fuse-ld=bfd.exe

clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/2A5F91C969E4FFC9A8676233A72536C1.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/21A4BB329148B5071B644FD4BC5D5B42.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/64417B2C5EE8B8E4EAA331E6132F7695.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/68F2BA2FF8C2240FC42B55FBD7110684.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/0ECEED10B69623FEE4CC1E1C4D31CB6E.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/9E0402F449353720EB7CE95F367A7EF8.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/314B1EA05E0EE6DB9D3EFDB7A0C7BC59.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/5DAA089FF9EC9678100CF815F4F50F36.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/406D283E7A0DD4611195A8E4C759DEFE.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/8EED78F7FA49F6E1E3BE27BBB365266E.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/956D91C4D4EECC1DF7A65BF030F1A326.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/BBA2D057883A3F7A9025808C7A1B113C.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/1DA1794CEC706FE0DCBF81814803801F.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/03D36EF9BE70819D163CA353AFC9F05B.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/4A57C8E929379DB51733B960C691C141.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/F060704F5C520D71DA3D646B71884165.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/297614B2657DC6C646FAD875273EF645.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/72B5AAB70492C9008A111014BEE10D6D.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/D24B0DB4947D1BD8F33B11F0FA25B9D1.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/346AF48F018DA20C4B469EE38BDEEC21.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/8D70E26F7E4ECB6D8AE6B3E4B603E31B.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/DC824F87FFC2E1F2B708DB68751A8699.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/CF77AB7347FE4FFA290803AF33E38C30.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/8826D088761B96EA8D7284D66DD23AE9.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/C849A58F8E21682C1EB3CA71B4102691.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/8B15CB46D81288B54EDFE4E47E188D32.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/E7D911DB5EE8D0B8DFF4C1122B75F176.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/532A1197902C98FC7A02B1F960A5DEF3.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/DAB19DD604714EEF4782E1B909213E48.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/06537C76E9114E402F8C49F31DFAE469.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/77C03E8561EA6D6212625E30E20A139C.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/E9DE33DCCF04D6DE9881053FFD7ECFD4.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/E423A9F2B7C8E98F31187D63180C2892.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/8E65B8500F41D1579ED29109E8631221.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/D583BB4A02696A5AF56C8742B76710D9.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/C409E679185CA015D8D721558457E73C.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/3B9C709F6B51EA111181F7C56F51F53F.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/52D78A4E6FAD64DA2B4FEEC206869395.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/6B2B78B58DCB88E7F36E6D1181953D68.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/268BE5F1663B544F34D62115BA5AB9D4.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/DAE4BBB268B14B10F4FF334FC704CB36.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/ACB01A3D5ACB1089170FE2B75035FF97.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/EC1C09FC88E8BCF1F1717AD5B7E6F972.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/12C982AE74C57DDB2B374DC71E5112E8.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/DB72B3FA6298F8DE8F83072224C3DF1B.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/9C2F89AF0E92E77A4A90D7AC0A06DA11.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/DB0D4D02BDA0F5607E16FA17884BEF2C.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/DDEC98DDC6611A73EA59DEBF09503656.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/EA0A4B20E8794D8C3CB5B98E63F5BADD.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/B2163C27222A5AD94C9DECF3B6126B59.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/3BFA5628E7EF36182F4A7CFD7AED0933.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/A670C6B6C4CC25337307ECDBBD1A8E48.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/C3E6E92BCF54505539A33FD04EE6A226.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/12F791580CD9B9299926A98DD042C2C0.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/4F682C631BDE3A97B3BAC3768B452EC9.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/3D9C56FEED60FF888AE4657A3BC45E0D.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/790E74D5466E01FAEECADEEF06875A46.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/57A3B1C1007CCD7845544514F18CAF08.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/7182B0EE443292D5DDC5BAA9E5BA4029.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/C11F8E2F7AC1220706C4A09CE4BE1A37.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/C4FCD84A21C41D8E9AFC90ECD93E0C8C.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/libil2cpp/37D744A57C61CA865A994BDBF823BF15.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/F77E6554E283D6AFE526889599CF0BA7.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/137542854D16EAAE714FF45D0DD3C411.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/696B233B17B5278764C78E4260468CA8.o'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project name has any strange characters like parentheses or dashes then you should remove them. Try to use only alphabetical characters in the project name and your problem should be fixed. Also make sure the directory unity is in doesn't have any strange characters as well

Comment: there is no such sign as parenthesis in the name anyway

Comment: too long to write. I am sending it as a text file.

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/file/u9yw512avlgxbnd/error.txt/file

Comment: C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Yaz?l?m/Unity Engine/Oyun Projeleri/the game/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/2A5F91C969E4FFC9A8676233A72536C1.o'  Yaz?l?m is the culprit. Rename the directory or move Unity to another one

Comment: I forgot to mention in the answer that you need to make sure the directory unity is in doesn't have any strange characters as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Unity/Unity Hub have admin privileges. Run Unity/Unity hub as administrator.